# UWP Create Custom Control => modified GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10

for a recent project I would need to modify the standard GridView. I need to specify the exact amount of columns/rows and to have the GridView scrollable in 2 dimensions. The standard GridView let you specify a MaxColumn/Row... I would need a MinColumn/Row...

I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction. Where do I nee to override a method?! Where can I do the math to position the GridViewItems and how should I do the scrolling?

I'm searching the web, but couldn't find a really good example

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I've created a custom Panel, which works great.

Comment: Hi folks, I was to quick. I still have some trouble: 1. how can access my custom panel from code behind to modify my own properties? 2. what do I need to do to refresh the whole layout? Some items are not rendered properly?